# filtering data in a text file using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to filter rows based on one column in a big text file. here is a small example:

`example`:

```
-3261   1
777 1
-45574  1
1017    1
-2802   1
969 1
1800    1
-128768 1
-7614   1
-136751 1
-64104  1
134844  1
```

I want to filter based on the first column. if the numbers in the 1st column are smaller than 4000 or larger than -4000 keep the row and filter out the rest. here is the expected output:

`expected output`:

```
-3261   1
777 1
1017    1
-2802   1
969 1
1800    1
```

I am using `awk` using this code:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ if($1 >= -4000 || $1 <= 4000) { print } }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

using this code output is the same as input file. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You should put `&&` AND condition since both conditions should be TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, you should know that

> smaller than 4000 **or** larger than -4000

and

> smaller than 4000 **AND** larger than -4000

are different.

`-80000` is valid for the `OR` condition, however not for the 2nd. I hope you meant the right thing. For your requirement, (the *OR* one), you can do (following your "or" requirement ):

```
awk '$1>=-4000 || $1<=4000'   file
```

Note, this will first check `>=-4000`,  that is, a row with value `99999999` will be valid, in output.

If you meant the **AND** condition, you need:

```
awk '$1<4000 && $1>-4000' file
```

Answer (score 2):

another way to write this

```
$ awk '$1^2 <= 4000^2' input_file
```

Comment: How does that handle the ">= -4000" case ?

Comment: due to symmetry, in words when you say x within +/-4000, similarly you can say x^2 less than 4000^2.  Perhaps easier this way: x>-4000, means abs(x)<4000 for negative x.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '$1<4000 && $1>-4000'   Input_file
```

Where is your code going wrong, you need to put `&&` condition since you want to check both conditions to be TRUE. `||` conditions will print those elements also where anyone of the conditions is TRUE too.

***More information on `&&` and `||` operators from `man awk` page:***

> ```
>    The &&, ||, and !  operators are logical AND, logical OR, and logical NOT, respectively, as in C.  They do short-circuit evaluation,
> ```
>
> also as  in
>          C,  and are used for combining more primitive pattern expressions.  As in most languages, parentheses may be used to change
>   the order of evalua-
>          tion.